# Running sum for subgroups of records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to calculate a running total for groups of data within a table (in SQL Server 2014). Please see the example below. I need to calculate the `RunningTotalByID` column.

[image]

Any thoughts/ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Insert the image directly in your question, it will help people understand your question quicker.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2014 supports `SUM() OVER (PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...)`, which calculates running sum:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID char(1), Value int);

INSERT INTO @T (ID, Value) VALUES
('A', 1),
('A', 1),
('B', 1),
('B', 1),
('B', 1),
('C', 1),
('C', 1);

SELECT
    ID
    ,Value
    ,SUM(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Value 
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS RunningTotal
FROM @T
ORDER BY ID, RunningTotal;
```

**Result**

```
+----+-------+--------------+
| ID | Value | RunningTotal |
+----+-------+--------------+
| A  |     1 |            1 |
| A  |     1 |            2 |
| B  |     1 |            1 |
| B  |     1 |            2 |
| B  |     1 |            3 |
| C  |     1 |            1 |
| C  |     1 |            2 |
+----+-------+--------------+
```